# Does a CustomAction menu item apply to child content types?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a CustomAction definition with RegistrationType="ContentType":

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Id="Sample.DuplicateListItem"
        Location="EditControlBlock"
        Title="Copy Item..."
        RegistrationType="ContentType"
        RegistrationId="0x01010012">
        <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/TheKidListActions/CopyListItem.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}"/>   
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

All document libraries which use this content type will show this context item menu.

My question is, will this context item menu be shown for a list which has a content type  0x010100120013 (inherited from 0x01010012)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't had a Change to Try it but it is Yes that, when you Associate the CustomAction to the  Parent content it will get pushed to the Child as well.

I got this information from the [Link](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2009/05/25/customaction-basics-in-sharepoint/)

> RegistrationId – The identifier of what will get this CustomAction attached to it.  Since we have chosen to attach by content type and our RegistrationId is 0×01, we are attaching this CustomAction to the Item content type and all that inherit from it.